# What is the motivation of arrow functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I've been working in Javascript. Lately they've added arrow functions in ES6 which have benefits as

1. Short Syntax
2. Scope safety of `this`
3. Clarity

However it has some disadvantage of using arrow function:

1. It doesn't inherit the `Function` prototype
2. We can't use it with callback function with dynamic context
3. Can't be used as constructor

I want to ask following things:

1. Why do they not inherit the `Function` prototype?
2. Are they made to increase the usage functional programming in javascript? (motivation behind them)

I asked this because [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) page says that it doesn't have a prototype but doesn't explain why it doesn't have a prototype.

I read [this](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/the-rise-and-fall-and-rise-of-functional-programming-composable-software-c2d91b424c8c) series by Eric Elliot and I think we're moving on functional programming approach in javascript and due to planned releases, is there any chance that we can remove OOPS in this in near future?

Comment: 1) They do: `Function.prototype === (() => {}).__proto__`

Comment: "We can't use it with callback function with dynamic context" — Instead you can use it as a callback function with preserved context. That's an advantage, not a disadvantage.

Comment: You're question seems to be "What's the point of arrow functions if they aren't exactly the same as function expressions?". I'd suggest that differences are the point, and that pointlessness would come from them not being different.

Comment: What's "*OOPS*"?

Comment: Eric Elliot is just trying to religiously dictate his own style of programming (in most of his articles.)

Comment: *"It doesn't inherit the Function prototype"* Only constructor functions will have a prototype *property*. So, for example, an object literal doesn't have a prototype *property*. But all objects do inherit from a prototype *object*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It doesn't inherit the Function prototype

Of course they do.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(() => {}) === Function.prototype
```

> We can't use it with callback function with dynamic context and it can't be used as constructor

Yes, that follows logically from the lexical `this` scope.

> Are they made to increase the usage functional programming in javascript?

No, they're made to simplify writing functions, e.g. callbacks. Of course that makes them also useful for functional programming, but I don't think that's the primary motivation. The lexical `this` is an explicit OOP feature.

Comment: "Arrow functions do not have a prototype property." - mdn. Are you babellifying it because then it will be es5 function then.

Comment: A prototype **property**, not that they are without a prototype.

Comment: @AjayGaur That means that `"prototype" in () => {}` is false, and has nothing to do with inheritance. They don't need that property because they're not constructors from which you can instantiate objects.

Answer (score 0):

The statement on Function inheritance is false and was likely confused with the fact that they [don't have `prototype` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Use_of_prototype_property). This is a direct consequence of the fact that they can't be constructors. A function that can't construct an object with `new` doesn't need `prototype`.

That's what they are, functions that don't have their own `this` context, they keep lexical `this` instead. They aren't just a shorter way to type `function`. Their potential use cases are all sorts of callbacks that need to keep the context or don't use `this` at all. If an arrow doesn't suit the case, that's the case for regular `function` then.

ES2015 arrows were borrowed from CoffeeScript where they have been proving their usefulness for a long time.